# Magento 2: How to display the list of manufacturers in a drop-down

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, drop-downs, manufacturer

i have a dropdown ui-component in which i want to display a list of manufacturers.

In the example below, i have a working drop-down with shipping methods.

```
<field name="manufacturer_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Manufacturer</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Is there an easy way of passing a class instead of *Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods* to get the list of manufacturers?

From [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205972/magento2-get-all-manufacturers), getting the manufacturers is done via product attributes

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface $attribute */
$attribute = $om->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface::class)
    ->get('manufacturer');

foreach ($attribute->getOptions() as $option) {
     var_dump($option->getValue() . ' -> ' . $option->getLabel());
}
```

But how do i assign this data to my drop-down (and in what format?) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show the options for a select UI component. I think this question have been answered [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286668/get-product-attribute-in-ui-component-form-magento-2) maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, that actually helped me, even the answer from that question was related to showing all product attributes, i took only manufacturers (based on the my code above for getting manufacturers).

Comment: Glad I could help